# How to access custom fonts from library project?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, assets

I had created an android library project.I Used custom fonts from my assets folder in my xml. But I can't access fonts from asset folder of the library project after integrated it with another project.I can access it from asset folder of new project.When i used with library project, it force closed and shows the error "native typeface cannot be made". How can I access asset folder fonts from library project ?? Is it possible ?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Your description is not clear, you should provide your code.

To access fonts from assets, you need to put the method inside the onCreate() method, then you can create your own typeface with the font in assets/fonts folder

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/font.ttf");

}
```

Comment: People who down-voted please give me the reasons, that would help me much. Thanks